# Disabling Windows 10 Game Bar for specific application

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-10, vcl

In some conditions the Windows 10's game bar opens up with my application (made with Delphi, VCL). Thats not a game and i don't directly use DirectX or OpenGL, but it opens up.

To be specific, when i reduce to tray my app and a popup is opened the Game Bar appears.

I found a numbers of sites with tutorial for totally disable the Windows 10 game bar (like [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8637-game-bar-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)) but i want to disable for my application only, i don't think users will be happy to have a windows feature silently disabled by my app

Is this possible? I cannot find any documentation about it

Comment: What is you executable filename? What if you change it to something else? I heard (no source) that it is partly based on exe filenames.

Comment: well, i cannot tell the exe name since is a commercial product, but it has that name from 10 years and we cannot change it. But.. renaming it with "mytest.exe".. the game bar is gone! My exe have a fairly common name so maybe a game with the same name can exists. If i change the directory without renaming the game bar is still there. I hope there is some other way to block it

Comment: Found a source in Drakes answer for this here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b0c2d32-3eb5-4245-89be-cfbc2f971ee5/how-to-disable-the-quotgame-barquot-or-quotmsgamingoverlayquot-for-my-c-native?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Answer (score 5):

You can disable it following this solution : 
Press Win+G, click the Gear icon (Settings) and uncheck "Remember this is a game" (https://superuser.com/questions/1086248/windows-10-xbox-dvr-app-thinks-chrome-is-a-game).

Note that if the name of the application is Main.exe, this checkbox is not visible.
If the name of the app is main.exe or anything else, it is visible.

It seems it is stored in the registry : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore\ in the Children and Parents directories.
You can try to find your app using the ExeParentDirectory key.
https://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/comments/3fbu0x/win_10_game_bardvr_anyone_having_issues/

I don't know if it applies to an executable where Windows decides it is a game (like Main.exe)

Comment: this is not what i need. I have to ship a product that doesn't popup the gamebar on my clients pc. Also, in the latest windows 10 version, the "Remember this is a game" check have been changed to a "not application specific check". 
Also, there is no ExeParentDirectory key in parent nor children keys, even after checking the "don't show this anymore" box inside the game bar

Comment: This was helpful since for some reason 'explorer.exe' got tagged as a game and I couldn't uncheck it.  I examined a clean pc and confirmed it's not supposed to be there; once I removed it, the checkbox doesn't even show up so it must be hard-coded in the UI to not allow it, but that doesn't help with whatever glitch added it